# Undefined reference to function Android NDK

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

Im trying to build Android app with existing c++ code which use OpenCV.
But Android NDK says that " undefined reference to 'TestMath::getHello()' "

Here is my Android.mk :

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
#opencv
OPENCVROOT := /mypath/OpenCV-android-sdk
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES := off
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES := off
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE := SHARED
include ${OPENCVROOT}/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE := CrossMath
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := com_testapp_recognition_TestMath.cpp
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := -lopencv_java3
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Application.mk :

```
APP_ABI := all
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions -std=c++11
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_PLATFORM := android-16
```

com_testapp_recognition_TestMath.hpp :

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "CrossMath/TestMath.hpp"
#ifndef _Included_com_testapp_recognition_TestMath
#define _Included_com_testapp_recognition_TestMath

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_testapp_recognition_TestMath_recognize(JNIEnv *, jobject, cv::Mat& originalImage);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

com_testapp_recognition_TestMath.cpp:

```
#include "com_testapp_recognition_TestMath.hpp"
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_testapp_recognition_TestMath_recognize(JNIEnv *, jobject, cv::Mat& originalImage) {
     return TestMath::getHello().size();
}
```

And finally TestMath.cpp which located in subfolder CrossMath:

```
#include "TestMath.hpp"

namespace TestMath {
     string getHello() {
         return "Hello";
     }
}
```

TestMath.hpp :

```
#ifndef TestMath_hpp
#define TestMath_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/core/core_c.h"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"

namespace TestMath {
    string getHello();
}
```

Java classes and other staff defined, I checked path and includes in files.

Error:

```
Error:(13) undefined reference to `TestMath::getHello()'
```

Comment: Please add the full and exact error message. I don't really see the point of `CrossMath/TestMath.hpp`. Function implementations aren't supposed to be placed in header files.

Comment: @Michael It is obviously typo ...

Comment: What's `string` supposed to be? `std::string`? If so, where are you including `<string>`, and where are you stating that you want it to be `string` from the `std` namespace?

Comment: if problem would be in string type error would be another, anyway, I added <string> nothing changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `CrossMath/TestMath.cpp` in your `LOCAL_SRC_FILES`.

In addition to that, if the `string` you refer to in your code is supposed to be `std::string` you need to include `<string>` in `TestMath.hpp` and change the type to `std::string`.

Comment: According to [android.mk](http://android.mk/) "you don't need to list header files or explicit dependencies between generated files in your Android.mk" Or it mean to not put there .hpp files?

Comment: That refers to header files, and generated files (whatever that means). `LOCAL_SRC_FILES` should contain _"the list of source files that the build system uses to generate the module"_.

Answer (score 0):

the error message "undefined reference to 'TestMath::getHello()' " says the NDK tools can not find the implementation of `TestMath::getHello()`.

try below com_testapp_recognition_TestMath.cpp:

```
#include "TestMath.hpp"
namespace TestMath {
    string getHello() {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
#include "com_testapp_recognition_TestMath.hpp"
    JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_testapp_recognition_TestMath_recognize(JNIEnv *, jobject, cv::Mat& originalImage) {
    return TestMath::getHello().size();
}
```

Comment: the main goal to not write whole implementation in com_testapp_recognition_TestMath.cpp. But include parts of pure c++ code to run from JNI wrapper.